# Le genre des abréviations

Tags: genre, abréviations

En réflichissant sur le substantif *zoo*, je me suis demandé quelle est la raison véritable pour laquelle il est masculin ? Ou c'est à cause de la forme du mot lui-même (oops ! *radio* arbore aussi cet *o* final), ou ça découle du genre du noyau du sytagme abrégé, à savoir ou ***jardin*** ou ***parc** zoologique*.

À cause des limitations de ma connaissance du français, je n’ai pu penser qu’à une poignée d’abréviations comparables : les acronymes *COP* et *OTAN*. Le premier s’accorde avec le substantif *conférence*. Mais le deuxième, en commencant en *O*, cache son genre au moyen de faire supprimer la voyelle de l’article : *le* ou *la* ? Attendez, il y a aussi ***le** PNB*. Et je viens de découvrir qu’on dit ***le** FN* en parlant **du** Front National et ***la** FN* quand il s’agit de ***la** Fabrique Nationale*, ancien constructeur belge des motos.

En parlant des motos, on a ***la** moto*, et le mot vient de ***la** motocyclette*. Ainsi ***le** vélo* vient du substantif masculin *vélocipède*.

Sur la base de ces bribes de preuves, je conjecture que le genre des abréviations est toujours celui du noyau du sytagme abrégé. Ai-je raison ? Si oui, les francophones disposent d’un truc qui est indisponible aux anglophones pour déchiffrer une abréviation : son genre est un indice utile et, en outre, il réduit de moitié les définitions potentielles.

Comment: Je peux vous suggérer le site suivant: https://www.usherbrooke.ca/usito/mediatheque/chroniques/les-sigles-et-acronymes-ont-ils-un-genre
Ou d'autres sites trouvés en tapant abréviation genre dans un moteur de recherche.

Comment: Il faudrait abréger _abbréviation_ dans le titre aussi, en français.

Comment: Je pense que c'est ça, on voit aussi que quand le genre du noyau est pas clair, on peut hésiter sur le genre, typiquement avec "*le/la wifi*". C'est pas toujours confus pour les abréviations venant d'autres langues, puisque que pour le FBI ou la CIA on s'en sort très bien (masculin pour *bureau* et féminin pour *agency/agence*)

Comment: @MasB, l’article que vous citez est très intéressante. En la parcourant je me suis rendu compte d’autres exemples qui ne s’agissent pas de sigles. Je l’ai modifiée pour en ajouter deux :  *moto* et *vélo*.

Comment: Quelle serait la forme préférée, @Frank ?

Comment: Ah ! J’avais employé double-*b* comme en anglais.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum For the record, I had to double check that in French, we use only one 'b' :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En général, le genre d'une abbréviation est le même que ce qu'elle abrège.

- une conférence des parties → une COP (on utilise l'abréviation anglaise)
- une organisation des Nations Unies → une ONU
- un produit national brut → un PNB
- une diode électroluminescente → une LED
- une automobile → une auto
- un vélocipède → un vélo
- la communauté urbaine de Lyon → la [COURLY](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communaut%C3%A9_urbaine_de_Lyon)
- le ministère de l'économie et des finances → le [MINÉFI](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/MINEFI)

L'[Académie française](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/QDL079) et un [chroniqueur hébergé par Terminum Plus](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/chroniq/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_titls&page=9pSnNKHVajyY.html) présentent cette règle comme le genre du nom principal dans un sigle qui abrège plusieurs mots. Mais en fait, la règle est plus simple et plus générale : c'est le genre qu'on utiliserait si on n'abrégeait pas.

Et comme toujours, en français, quand il y a une règle, il y a des exceptions. La plupart des exceptions sont des cas où la version longue est mal connue. Par exemple, [HLM](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitation_%C3%A0_loyer_mod%C3%A9r%C3%A9) est *une* habitation à loyer modéré, mais on dit plus souvent « un HLM ». C'est peut-être parce que « [un] habitat à loyer modéré » serait une expansion plausible de l'abréviation.

Curieusement, je vois des fois OTAN (une organisation …) au masculin (contrairement à d'autres organisations comme l'ONU, l'OPEP...), même si cela reste minoritaire. Je ne sais pas pourquoi. On l'appelle aussi « l'alliance Atlantique », qui est féminin. Dans l'autre sens, « un OGM » (un organisme génétiquement modifié) se trouve aussi minoritairement au féminin « <sup>?</sup>une OGM » — peut-être parce qu'il s'agit en général d'*une* plante ?

Lorsqu'on utilise une abréviation étrangère, on fait en général comme si elle était traduite mot à mot : la [CDU](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_chr%C3%A9tienne-d%C3%A9mocrate_d%27Allemagne) (union), le [SPD](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parti_social-d%C3%A9mocrate_d%27Allemagne) (parti), la [CIA](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Intelligence_Agency) (agence), le [KGB](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/KGB) (comité). Mais le genre peut être plus flou quand il n'y a pas de traduction évidente ou qu'il y a plusieurs possibilités. Dans ces cas, l'usage peut varier ou venir d'une autre raison : un choix par catégorie ou arbitraire. (Le choix par catégorie est ce qui se passe pour les noms propres : « le *Labour* » en politique anglaise parce que c'est *un* parti ; mais le choix de nom pour désigner la catégorie peut aussi être ambigu.)